# Wifi doesn't find any networks after 18.04.3 update

Tags: networking, wireless, updates

Edit: After reinstalling the network manager the WiFi worked for 2 days, but now again it appears to be on, but doesn't show any available networks. I tried to connect to to the networks by the "connect to hidden networks" option, but that also failed.
`sudo systemctl restart network-manager` doesn't show a message anymore and seems to restart the network (I'm connected to the internet via an USB cable to my phone)
`systemctl status NetworkManager` shows:

> ● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
>     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; 
>   enabled; vendor p
>     Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-09-26 11:40:55 +07; 4min > 8s ago
>       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
>   Main PID: 3202 (NetworkManager)
>      Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
>     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
>             ├─3202 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
>             └─3222 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager
>   /nm-dhcp-helpe
>
> Sep 26 11:40:56 mehrdad-Latitude NetworkManager[3202]: 
>   [1569472856.3530]
>   Sep 26 11:40:56 mehrdad-Latitude NetworkManager[3202]: 
>   [1569472856.3532]
>   Sep 26 11:40:56 mehrdad-Latitude NetworkManager[3202]: 
>   [1569472856.3599]
>   Sep 26 11:40:56 mehrdad-Latitude NetworkManager[3202]: 
>   [1569472856.3601]
>   Sep 26 11:40:56 mehrdad-Latitude NetworkManager[3202]: 
>   [1569472856.3605]
>   Sep 26 11:40:56 mehrdad-Latitude dhclient[3222]: bound to 
>   192.168.42.112 -- rene
>   Sep 26 11:40:56 mehrdad-Latitude NetworkManager[3202]: 
>   [1569472856.3727]
>   Sep 26 11:40:56 mehrdad-Latitude NetworkManager[3202]: 
>   [1569472856.3729]
>   Sep 26 11:40:57 mehrdad-Latitude NetworkManager[3202]: 
>   [1569472857.6882]
>   Sep 26 11:41:01 mehrdad-Latitude NetworkManager[3202]: 
>   [1569472861.8343]

`sudo iwconfig` shows following:

> wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
>            Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm
>            Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>            Encryption key:off
>            Power Management:on
>
> enp0s20u1  no wireless extensions.
>
> eno1      no wireless extensions.
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.

Everything was fine before, but after I updated to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS just an hour or so ago, my WiFi doesn't find any networks.  I restarted my system several times and nothing changed.

Here's the output of 'lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list'

> 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit >Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
>     Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) >[1028:0533]
>     Kernel driver in use: e1000e
>     Kernel modules: e1000e
>    00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset
>    Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
>    --
>    02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228
>    802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
>     Subsystem: Dell BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [1028:0014]
>     Kernel driver in use: wl
>     Kernel modules: bcma, wl
>   1: phy0: Wireless LAN
>     Soft blocked: no
>     Hard blocked: no
>   2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
>     Soft blocked: no
>     Hard blocked: no
>   3: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
>     Soft blocked: no
>     Hard blocked: no
>   4: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
>     Soft blocked: no
>     Hard blocked: no
>   5: dell-wwan: Wireless WAN
>     Soft blocked: no
>     Hard blocked: no
>   7: hci0: Bluetooth
>     Soft blocked: no
>     Hard blocked: no

How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: From what version of Ubuntu did you upgrade from? Does `iwconfig` show anything? What about `systemctl status NetworkManager`? Please add to your question.

Comment: Now I restarted the laptop again after a few hours and it works again. I'm really confused

Answer (score 0):

If your network manager is not restarting then try to reinstall and restart your pc. Maybe it will work. 
Here is the network manager deb file find which one is suitable for you.
[network manager](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/)

I am not sure it will work or not ...

Comment: i picked the network manager file with the most recent date and it worked.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Today the WiFi worked at first, but after I restarted the computer it stopped working. The network manager shows me no available WiFi networks. I tried reinstalling the network manager and did several restarts, but it still doesn't work.